# attaching css class to ID's in a vue app

Tags: vue.js

First time SO poster here; I'm having some trouble with attaching a css class to an element with an ID; the way i'm doing it with classes is i have a click event on an HTML element that triggers a property to toggle state, and that property returns the new class, which works great.

When doing this and targeting an ID, i'm not too sure what i'm missing; I can get the click event to toggle state, but i'm not sure how to attach a class to that element ID. I've pasted the codepen below; thank you in advance.

https://codepen.io/KarimPremji/pen/vJYKWB

```
  <!-- testing ID binding-->
  <div id="excerciseID" @click="turnPink = !turnPink" 
  :class="divClassesPink"></div>
  <br>TurnPink state: {{turnPink}}
  </div>

new Vue({
el: '#app',
  data: {
    turnRed: false,
    turnPink: false
  },
  computed: {
divClassesRed: function(){
  return {
    red: this.turnRed,
    blue: !this.turnRed
  }
},
divClassesPink: function(){
  return {
    pink: this.turnPink,
    blue: !this.turnPink
  }
}
  }})
```

Answer (score 1):

This is not a Vue issue, it's a CSS issue. Your ID selector is [*more specific*](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Specificity) than a class and the `background-color: gray` will be the color rendered.

> The following list of selector types increases by specificity:
>
> 1. Type selectors (e.g., h1) and pseudo-elements (e.g., :before).
> 2. Class selectors (e.g., .example), attributes selectors (e.g., [type="radio"]) and pseudo-classes (e.g., :hover).
> 3. ID selectors (e.g., #example).

In your CSS you have the following rules.

```
.red{
  background-color: red;
}

.blue{
  background-color: blue;
}

.pink{
  background-color: pink;
}

#excerciseID { // This is the most specific CSS rule
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background-color: gray; // remove this
  margin: 10px;
  display: inline-block;
}
```

If you want to toggle the color, then you should remove that line. Here is your [pen updated](https://codepen.io/Kradek/pen/ZJEpYm).

Comment: Thanks a lot to both of you gents, really appreciate it!

Comment: @KarimPremji please accept an answer you liked and upvote both of them if you appreciate both the answers :)

Answer (score 0):

Remove `background-color: grey` from your `#exerciseID` CSS rules.

CSS rules for elements selected by an ID have a higher priority so that's why it stays grey.

Here is an updated [codepen](https://codepen.io/ikbelkirasan/pen/mMdryO).